# Using Guava Iterables.cycle as a circular list impl

Tags: java, algorithm, list, data-structures, guava

I have a `List<Widget>` and am looking for the most efficient/elegant solution to loop over it, again and again (kind of like a round robin algorithm):

```
// Returns a list of 20 widgets, with an id of 1 - 20 respectively.
List<Widget> widgets = getWidgets();
Widget widget = pickWidget(); // Returns the 1st widget with id = 1.
widget = pickWidget(); // Returns the 2nd widget with id = 2.
widget = pickWidget(); // Return the 3rd widget with id = 3.
// ..etc.
widget = pickWidget(); // Returns the 19th widget with id = 19.
widget = pickWidget(); // Returns the 20th widget with id = 20.
widget = pickWidget(); // Returns the 1st widget with id = 1 (it cycle back).
```

That's the usage, for the implementation the best I've been able to find is Guava's [`Iterables.cycle(...)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#cycle(java.lang.Iterable)):

```
Widget pickWidget() {
    for(Widget w : Iterables.cycle(widgets)) {
        return w;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `cycle` doesn't leave a marker inside `widgets` so that it can "remember" where it let off the last time `pickWidget()` was called.

Any ideas here? Apache's `CircularFifoQueue` seems close but no cigar, as I don't want anything popped off the queue, I just want it to cycle over the same list time and time again as it is called.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't need to leave any marker. The Iterator of the Iterable returned by cycle() keeps that mark internally. All you need is to keep a reference to this iterator:

```
private Iterator<Widget> cyclingIterator = Iterables.cycle(widgets).iterator();

public Widget pick() {
    return cyclingIterator.next();
}
```

Or simply, since you don't actually need the Iterable, but only the iterator:

```
private Iterator<Widget> cyclingIterator = Iterators.cycle(widgets);

public Widget pick() {
    return cyclingIterator.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't leave a marker because that's not the purpose of an `iterator()` -- it doesn't persist anything between calls.

How about just:

```
private int pos = 0;
Widget pickWidget() {
    return widgets.get(pos++ % widets.size());
}
```

Comment: Err, that's precisely the purpose of an Iterator, and it does persist between calls.

Comment: @JBNizet The iterator object does maintain state, the `iterator()` method doesn't since it will give you a new object usually :)

Comment: Your initial post didn't have the parentheses after iterator. Since the iterator does maintain state, why not use it? Your method forgets to increment pos, and will be very inefficient if the list is not RandomAccess.

Comment: Indeed I made this post hastily. OP doesn't show the full code but it is a simple solution that doesn't require any libraries and may work for OP.